# How to assign two functions to a single button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I only know how to assign a script to a button in Google Sheets but I don't know how to assign two or three function(scripts) to a single button. That when I press the button in making invoice the invoice change number, saves to next sheet, and print. How could it be.how can i run combine these three scripts at one in google sheets.

```js
function export() {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Unwanted Sheet');
  sheet.hideSheet();
  DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());
  sheet.showSheet();
}



function clearRange2() { //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('A10:F26').clearContent();
}






  function clearRange2() { //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('A10:F26').clearContent();
         }
}
```

Comment: Write a function bound to the script that calls the other three?

Comment: three functions have different name, like printPdf, nextinvoiceNumber, and clearOldbill
how to write it for button

Comment: you write a function `runAll(){printPdf(); nextInvoiceNumber(); clearOldbill();}` and assign that to the button

Comment: i wanna run the above three scripts with a button

Comment: i tried above method but it have a problem it save an empty bill because tow function run at once fist is save the products second is clear bill to make a new but the function clears then save to drive

Answer (score 0):

Make another function that calls all the functions you need, then assign that function to the button.
Also if you are calling those functions from the same button, maybe those functions should all be combined into one function?